# Laravel "At Least One" Field Required Validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

So I have this form with these fields

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'user', 'id' => 'user_create_form')) }}

    <div class="form-input-element">
        <label for="facebook_id">ID Facebook</label>
        {{ Form::text('facebook_id', Input::old('facebook_id'), array('placeholder' => 'ID Facebook')) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-input-element">
        <label for="twitter_id">ID Twitter</label>
        {{ Form::text('twitter_id', Input::old('twitter_id'), array('placeholder' => 'ID Twitter')) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-input-element">
        <label for="instagram_id">ID Instagram</label>
        {{ Form::text('instagram_id', Input::old('instagram_id'), array('placeholder' => 'ID Instagram')) }}
    </div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

I'd like to tell Laravel that at least one of these fields is required. How do I do that using the Validator?

```
$rules = array(
    'facebook_id'                   => 'required',
    'twitter_id'                    => 'required',
    'instagram_id'                  => 'required',
);
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
```

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Try checking out [`required_without_all:foo,bar,...`](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-required-without-all), it looks like that should do it for you.  To quote their documentation:

> The field under validation must be present only when the all of the other specified fields are not present.

---

## Example:

```
$rules = array(
    'facebook_id' => 'required_without_all:twitter_id,instagram_id',
    'twitter_id' => 'required_without_all:facebook_id,instagram_id',
    'instagram_id' => 'required_without_all:facebook_id,twitter_id',
);
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
```

Comment: This works but the problem is the repetition of messages. If you want to avoid that you can try the way https://stackoverflow.com/a/65806163/959260

Answer (score 9):

```
**For automatic validation**

$rules = array(
    'facebook_id' => 'required_without_all:twitter_id,instagram_id',
    'twitter_id' => 'required_without_all:facebook_id,instagram_id',
    'instagram_id' => 'required_without_all:facebook_id,twitter_id',
);
$message = array(
    'facebook_id' => 'The facebook field is required when none of twitter / instagram are present.',
    'twitter_id' => 'The twitter field is required when none of facebook / instagram are present.',
    'instagram_id' => 'The instagram field is required when none of twitter / facebook are present.');

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $message)->validate();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to implement with an [After Validation Hook](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#after-validation-hook):

```
$validator->after(function ($validator) {
    if (empty($this->validated())) {
        $validator->errors()->add('empty', 'At least one field must be provided.');
    }
});
```

Or if you are using a ***FormRequest***:

```
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        if (empty($this->validated())) {
            $validator->errors()->add('empty', 'At least one field must be provided.');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code i already made it

```
php artisan make:rule RequiredWithout
```

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class RequiredWithout implements Rule
{
    private $without = [];
    private $current_attribute = "";
    private $no_need = "";

    public function __construct($without)
    {
        if(is_string($without))
        {
            $this->without = [$without];
        }
        elseif(is_array($without))
        {
            $this->without = $without;
        }
        else
           throw new \Exception('$without must be array or string');
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $this->current_attribute = $attribute;
        $requests = request()->all();
        foreach ($this->without as $WO_i)
        {            
            if(array_key_exists($WO_i, $requests))
            {
                $this->no_need = $WO_i;
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return "the $this->current_attribute Field and $this->no_need Shouldn't be Exist in this request together";
    }
}
```

and then in the controller use this

```
'country_id' => ['nullable', 'exists:countries,id', new ValidCountryID(), new RequiredWithout('country_code')],
'country_code' => ['nullable', 'exists:countries,IsoCountryCode', new ValidCountryID(), new RequiredWithout('country_id')],
```

Answer (score 0):

Rule `required_without_all` can be hacked to get the desired results.

Create a dummy rule for `require_one`, and pass all fields to the rule params. if none exists, the dummy rules fires up with required.

```
$rules = array(
  'facebook_id'                   => 'required',
  'twitter_id'                    => 'required',
  'instagram_id'                  => 'required',
);

$keys = implode(',', array_keys($rules));
$rules['require_one'] = "required_without_all:$keys";

$messages = [
  'require_one.required_without_all' => '*At least one field is required'
];


$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);
```