# Override single message for required_without_all laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have been using required_without_all for at least one field required in laravel. 
Here is my code for rule

```
'rental_company_id'         => 'required_without_all:camper_id,take_over_station_id,returnable_station_id',
'camper_id'                 => 'required_without_all:rental_company_id,take_over_station_id,returnable_station_id',
'take_over_station_id'      => 'required_without_all:rental_company_id,camper_id,returnable_station_id',
'returnable_station_id'     => 'required_without_all:rental_company_id,camper_id,take_over_station_id',
```

Here are my custom message which will override default message produced by laravel

```
'rental_company_id.required_without_all'                => 'The Rental Companies is required when none of Campers, Takeover stations and Returnable stations are present.',
'camper_id.required_without_all'                        => 'The Campers is required when none of Rental Companies, Takeover stations and Returnable stations are present.',
'take_over_station_id.required_without_all'             => 'The Takeover stations is required when none of Campers, Rental Companies and Returnable stations are present.',
'returnable_station_id.required_without_all'            => 'The Returnable stations is required when none of Campers, Rental Companies and Takeover stations are present.',
```

Instead of showing multiple line of error message to the user. is there any way I can sum up those four messages into single message like

> One of the following Season,Rental companies,... must be present.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve by adding custom rule `php artisan make:rule AssignDataValidation`

```
/**
 * Determine if the validation rule passes.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return bool
 */
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $isSet = false;
    $input = Input::all();
    foreach (Discount::ASSIGNED_DATA_FIELD as $data){
        if (isset($input[$data])){
            $isSet = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $isSet;
}

/**
 * Get the validation error message.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function message()
{
    return 'One of the following Season, Rental companies,... must be present.';
}
```

On Form request I have an override `getValidatorInstance()` method and invoke after validation to add my rule manually and trigger on error bag with the custom name

```
protected function getValidatorInstance()
{
    $validator = parent::getValidatorInstance();
    $validator -> after(function ($validator){
        $timeDataValidation     = new TimeDataValidation;
        $assignDataValidation   = new AssignDataValidation;
        if (!$timeDataValidation -> passes(TimeDataValidation::FIELD,Discount::TIME_DATA_FIELD)){
            $validator -> errors() -> add(TimeDataValidation::FIELD,$timeDataValidation -> message());
        }
        if (!$assignDataValidation -> passes(AssignDataValidation::FIELD,Discount::ASSIGNED_DATA_FIELD)){
            $validator -> errors() -> add(AssignDataValidation::FIELD,$assignDataValidation -> message());
        }
    });
    
    return $validator;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a very simple way you can achieve this. Apply the rule to a made-up `ids` field and then include all the actual fields for which you want validation applied after `required_without_all`. And just one corresponding validation message.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'ids' => 'required_without_all:rental_company_id,camper_id,take_over_station_id, returnable_station_id'
            ], [
            'required_without_all' => 'One of the following Season,Rental companies,... must be present.'
            ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a form request, you could do this in your `messages()` method:

```
return [
    'required_without_all' => 'One of the field must be present.'
];
```

If you are using a manual validator, you could do this:

```
$messages = [
    'required_without_all' => 'One of the field must be present.',
];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

**Edit**: An alternative would be to check if your MessageBag contains an error for one of those fields, and then display another one accordingly in your view. For example:

```
@if (
    $errors->has('rental_company_id')
    || $errors->has('camper_id')
    || $errors->has('take_over_station_id') 
    || $errors->has('returnable_station_id')
) {
    // display the error message you need
}
```

Admittedly, this is not pretty, but I can't seem to find another way of doing it.

Comment: I am using form request but I have to used required_without_all for other field and other case in same form. Sorry I have mislead my messages. I have edited my question.

Comment: In that case, I am not sure it is achievable from the Validator's perspective.

Comment: any other way you can recommend me to??

Comment: Edited my answer to add a *possible* alternative. Not a big fan of it, though.

Answer (score 2):

So... I wouldn't necessarily recommend this, but here's a quick and dirty way to prevent duplicate error messages when using `required_without_all` on multiple fields with the aim of an "at least one of these fields is required" type of rule:

1. In the controller, give your fields custom *identical* error messages (i.e. don't use `:attribute`):

```php
public function foo(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate(
        [
            // the "at least one of these" fields must be grouped together here.
            'field_1' => 'required_without_all:field_2|nullable|etc',
            'field_2' => 'required_without_all:field_1|nullable|etc',
            // etc...
        ],
        [
            'field_1.required_without_all' => 'At least one is required',
            'field_2.required_without_all' => 'At least one is required',
            // etc...
            // If this list of fields is the only time you're using
            // required_without_all, you can just use a single catch-all
            // ['required_without_all' => 'message'] instead
        ]
    );
}
```

2. Then, in your view check for duplicate error messages as you're looping/writing them:

```php
@if ($errors->any())
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            @if ($error !== ($prevError ?? ''))
                <li>{{ $prevError = $error }}</li>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

One of PHP's quirks(?) is that it returns the assigned value on variable assignment, which is why our `<li>` items will still contain the "at least one required" error text. The null coalescing `??` is just so that the `foreach` doesn't break on the first loop, before `$prevError` has been assigned.

Again... I'm not sure I could properly recommend doing this - there are several reasons why it's suboptimal. But if you need a quick and dirty way of achieving a "at least one of these" type rule you may find it useful.