# Laravel Schema: Require at least one of four columns is not null

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a structure that looks like this:

```
Attribute Values Table
+----+-----------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
| id | option_id | integer_value | price_value | text_value  |
+----+-----------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | 4         | NULL          | NULL        | NULL        |
|  2 | NULL      | 24            | NULL        | NULL        |
|  3 | NULL      | NULL          | NULL        | Lorem Ipsum |
|  4 | NULL      | NULL          | 30.50       | NULL        |
+----+-----------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
```

(Some columns were removed for brevity)

But basically the type of the entry can either be a reference to a select option (`option_id`), or an integer value (`integer_value`), or a decimal value (`price_value`), or a text value (`text_value`). One of the omitted columns is `attribute_id` which corresponds to an entry that has an enum which stores which one of these four columns is it.

Is there any way to add a constraint in the Laravel schema that at least one of these four columns has to be non-null?

Comment: Handle this as a validation constraint using the `required_without_all` rule. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401365/laravel-at-least-one-field-required-validation

Comment: By the way this is in violation of 1NF which requires all row/column intersections to have a value (or at least a value to be applicable to them even if you don't currently know it). In your case you have deliberately made a table which is only 40% not null

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks, but what would be the alternative? Just store everything as a string and convert it based on a type enum? What if I wanted to search for all integer values in a certain range, for example? Also then I couldn't do foreign key constraints on the option_id column.

Comment: 4 tables is how you'd normalise this

Answer (score 1):

If you will always have only one of these column filled at any time I would recomend altering your schema to just two colums

Like

```
+----------+--------------+------------+
|    id    |     value    |    type    |
+----------+--------------+------------+
```

Where the `value` will always have a value and `type` will contain the 4 types that you have mentioned

ie: `option_id`, `integer_value`, `price_value` and `text_value`

This way its clean.

In laravel you cannot add the specified constraint. You must validate your input before insertion.

However if you really want to add a database level constraint you could try adding a trigger before each insert to validate your need using the DB::unprepared function on the table.

and the trigger could look like this (I have not tried this)

```
DB::unprepared("
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER `foo`
    BEFORE INSERT ON `table`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF (
            new.option_id IS NULL
            AND new.integer_value IS NULL
            AND new.price_value IS NULL
            AND new.text_value IS NULL
        ) 
        THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' 
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'your message here';
        END IF;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
");
```